# Sampling distributions - why do I multiply by combination / permutation?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, sampling

Say I have a bag with a very large number of disks with the numbers $1$ and $2$ on them. Say the disks are present in the proportion $0.25$ to $0.75$. The number of disks is so large, removing $3$ disks has no impact on the proportion of each type of disk in the bag.

I remove three disks from the bag and I am interested in the sampling distribution of various statistics such as the median. For example, disks $112$ have a median of $1$.

Now when I look at the solution for questions of this type I have to multiply the combine probabilities by the permutation of the disks as if they were selected in order.
In the example drawing $112$ the “probability component” would be $(0.25)^2$ $(0.75)^1$. However, in the solutions provided I need to multiply this number by $3$ because of the three different ways of ordering the numbers on the disks: $112, 121$, and $211$.

What I don’t understand is why this multiplication by the number of possible ways of the position of the $2$, i.e. $\binom31$, is necessary. If I put my hand in the bag and select $3$ disks in one go, there is no sense in which there is a “first” disk or a “second” disk or a “third” disk, so why do I multiply by the permutation of the three objects?

*Update following comments from Siong and Dave K*

Ok. I think I understand. Consider P(A) = $0.25$, P(B) = $0.75$, A and B are independent events. By **my** model if three events could occur simultaneously the “3-events” would be: AAA, AAB, ABB, BBB where order would not be important so for example ABB = BAB = BBA etc. Hence, because A and B are independent $P(AAA) = 0.25^3, P(AAB) =(0.25)^2(0.75), P(ABB) = (0.25)(0.75)^2, P(BBB) =0.75^3$.

By **my** model, since the “3-events” are mutually exclusive and should be exhaustive, P(AAA) + P(AAB) + P(ABB) + P(BBB) = $\frac{1+3+9+27}{64} = \frac{40}{64}$ which is nonsense since the sum of all m.e. probabilities should be 1.

So **your** model is correct i.e. sum is $1(0.25^3) + 3(0.25)^2(0.75)+ 3(0.25)(0.75)^2 + 3(0.75^3) = 1$. Now I have to go away, and think is it possible to have a model of independent simultaneous events, ignoring any considerations of physical reality?

Comment: Hello Siong. You made a number of formatting changes to the numbers in my post. The result is the changed version doesn't read any different from the original (apart from a decision about how to represent a combination). Can you explain the reasons behind the changes so I can incorporate those in my posts from when I originally post them? Thanks.

Comment: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185193) is a discussion of why do we do it. Personally I admire numbers so I treat them differently from text.

Comment: Thanks for the link Siong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(0.25)^2(0.75)$ is the probability that you draw $(1,1,2)$ sequentially (i.e. when order matter)

It is also the probability that you draw $(1,2,1)$.

It is also the probability that you draw $(2,1,1)$.

However, if we do not care about the order, any of the above sequence is good. That is we want to conpute the probability that you get one of $(1,1,2), (1,2,1)$ or $(2,1,1)$, and hence we add them up.

If you care about the order, the following table is of interest to you:
\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
\text{outcome} & \text{probability} \\ \hline
(1,1,1) & (0.25)^3 \\ \hline
\color{blue}{(1,1,2)} & \color{blue}{(0.25)^2(0.75)} \\ \hline
\color{blue}{(1,2,1)} & \color{blue}{(0.25)^2(0.75)} \\ \hline
\color{blue}{(2,1,1)} & \color{blue}{(0.25)^2(0.75)}\\ \hline
(1,2,2) & (0.75)^2(0.25)\\ \hline
(2,2,1) & (0.75)^2(0.25)\\ \hline
(2,1,2) & (0.75)^2(0.25) \\ \hline
(2,2,2) & (0.75)^3 \\ \hline
\end{array}

If not, the following table which summarizes number of $2$ matters for you.

\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
\text{number of } 2 & \text{probability} \\ \hline
0 & (0.25)^3 \\ \hline
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{3(0.25)^2(0.75)} \\ \hline
2 & 3(0.75)^2(0.25)\\ \hline
3 & (0.75)^3 \\ \hline
\end{array}

See how the second table can be constructed from the first table by grouping rows together. Also notice that probabilty sums to $1$ in both table.

Comment: I understand what you have written but you haven't answered my question. You have just restated the "standarard" solution. Why is the permutation relevant if I pick all three balls at the same time?

Comment: If you pick the ball simultaneously, why would you multiply $0.25$, $0.25$ and then $0.75$, multiplication principle assume order.

Comment: A basic principle is that if the events are independent, they occur simultaneously and their probabilities don't change you just multiply the probabilities. You are asserting their is an order in the events when there isn't.

Comment: I see, what are your events in this case? are they independent?

Comment: The events are (i) selecting a disk with a '1' on it and (ii) selecting a disk with a '2' on it, given a 'sufficiently large bag' with in these problems is interpreted as "an infinite supply of disks" so that the probability of selecting either kind of disks is not affected (not dependent) on what you have previously drawn. Usual probability question (over-)simplification. What is your point?

Comment: I was hoping you reply with the events are $\{$ selecting a disk with a $1$ on it out of $3$ disks $\}$ and $\{$ selecting $2$ disks with $2$ on them out of $3$ disks \}$, of which actually those two are the same event, hence dependent.

Comment: I wonder if you can state $3$ independent events such that  $P(A_1, A_2, A_3)=P(A_1)P(A_2)P(A_3)$ because $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$ are independent.

Answer (score 0):

When you say there is no sense in which any disk is "first", you have merely *decided to ignore* any sense in which any disk is first.

In an actual physical implementation of this experiment,
you reach into a bag and touch disks with your fingers in order to pick them up and pull them out.
Without looking, can you guide your finger so accurately that it touches three disks simultaneously, none of them even one microsecond earlier than the others?
And then guide a second finger to grasp all three disks simultaneously from the other side so you can pick them all up at once?

Perhaps if there happens to be a stack of three disks near the mouth of the bag, we might charitably say you were lucky enough to grab that stack and that your fingers made contact with the edges of all three disks simultaneously. If the stack consists of one "2" and two "1"s, however, the "2" has to be somewhere in the stack--top, middle, or bottom.
That's three different ways to pick up the chips.

The fact that you may prefer to ignore these distinctions does not oblige everyone else to ignore them. And when watching someone draw three disks from a bag, where there is enough randomness and symmetry that the usual simplistic probability models work reasonably well, two different mathematicians should not get two radically different probability results for the same event. If they do, repeating the experiment multiple times will show  soon enough that the real world disagrees with one of the mathematicians.

If the chips were all in some sort of macroscopic quantum superposition such that every single chip "occupied" the exact same location in space as every other chip, you might be able to select three chips in such a way that there is actually no "order" in the selection at all.
In that case I'm not sure the usual balls-in-an-urn model applies.
But we tend to prefer models that are closer to something we can easily physically realize.

This exercise is easy enough to approximate in real life. You could take a pile of chips of one color and three times as many chips of another color,
mix them up in a big bag, pull out three chips, and then write a tick mark next to the word "yes" if you get two of color number 1 and one of color number 2, "no" in any other case.
Repeat the experiment a few dozen times and count how many tick marks you have written next to each word.
Compare the ratio to what you would expect by computing the probabilities without considering the three chips in sequence and what you would expect if you do consider them in sequence.
Which calculation was closer to the actual observation?

Comment: I thought of doing some kind of simulation and compare the actual results with the "no order" and the "order is relevant" approaches. Am I right in thinking, from your argument it is impossible to select "simultaneously" items from a bag where order is not important? Or to remove the double negative, selecting several items from a bag and only looking at them as a collection, that somehow order of selection is still relevant? it is that idea I am grappling with.

Comment: Here is another way of expressing my problem in understanding. Let's focus on the selecting. Let's say I actually do select the items separately, there's the first, there's the second, there's the third. But I don't look at the items drawn until I have selected them all and there is nothing to indicate the order they were drawn. The **information** about the order of drawing has been **lost**. So isn't that effectively "drawing them simultaneously"?

Comment: Suppose I _do_ look at the item you have drawn each time, even though you don't. So now I have recorded three items in a known sequence, and you only record three items in an unknown sequence. Whose record is more likely to include two 1s and one 2? Does the fact that I peeked cause the probability to change? (In quantum mechanics peeking _does_ change the probabilities of events, but chips in a bag don't exhibit quantum behaviors.)

Comment: @Dave K, going back to your original answer, although "in the real world", your argument is strong, I was thinking it wasn't relevant to the statistical model I was trying to construct of the situation. As it it turns out, my model was incorrect becasue it failed a basic property of the sum of mututally exclusive, exhaustive events. As I result I have to accept the need for the combinatorial coefficients in the model.

Comment: That is also a strong argument: if you take the "quantum superposition" model that I suggested and use that instead of the "usual" model, you have to somehow get the total probability to $1,$ which means the $(0.25)^n (0.75)^{3-n}$ formula by itself is still not enough to compute all the probabilities. Since that is the argument you found most persuasive, you were right to put the check mark next to the answer that demonstrates how the probabilities add to $1.$